# Embed multiple instances of a single html inside another html, but with different styles

Tags: html, css, include

I want to do some design testing, which is to display a lot of possible visual states of a GUI mockup, in a single view. For that, I am also using/learning browser-based techniques.

For that, I have a "window" html file, which should display a stack of these possible states, then a "mywidget" html file which contains the default state of this control.

My question is: how can I create (embed/include) multiple instances of this same layout, but style each one differently via CSS?

The plan is to take each instance, change the class of some elements, and have a single stylesheet with class-oriented styling.

I was thinking about using IFrame, but have no idea how to access the embeded stuff for CSS styling.

I would prefer non-javascript answers.

Also, I am going to use this locally/offline (not through a server), using FF exclusively, opening the master file directly via double-click.

Answer (score 1):

Allow your styles to be inherited from their wrappers:

```
<div class="sample1">
    <h1>some text</h1>
</div>

<div class="sample2">
    <h1>some text</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sample1 h1 {
     font-size:14px;
}

.sample2 h1 {
     font-size:22px;
}
```

This way you can use the same HTML without having to add class names to everything. Just change the wrapper class and make sets of CSS declarations to go with that class.

Only add class names where you really need them - keep it clean and simple as possible.

Comment: I would like to be able to alter the html structure in only one place, because it is most probable that I'd have to add or remove tags from it. Is there any way I could reuse the same single block of html to do what you suggested?

Comment: Use can use "display:none" to hide elements instead of removing them. Or you can add a class name to those items "hideMe" then declare .sample1 .hideMe { display:none }

Comment: I see. Even though, I am not very prone to have so much repeated html code... :o(

Answer (score 0):

with iframes it will not work out that easy. I use use ajax for that purpose and it works like a charm.